# Extracting email_address from a string in hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am new to hive
I have a string and I want to extract the email address from that string in hive

```
Select regexp_extract('my email address is xxxxxx@gmail.com', '@(.*)',0);
OK
@gmail.com
```

It is only extracting the domain name but I need the full email address i.e. 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'

I an new to regex

Comment: Try `'\\S+@\\S+'`

Comment: It is working, Can I mask this email address with in the same query ?

Comment: You might get it working with some kind of `regexp_replace(string, '\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+', '***@***.***')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
Select regexp_extract('my email address is xxxxxx@gmail.com', '\\S+@\\S+',0);
Select regexp_extract('my email address is xxxxxx@gmail.com', '\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+',0);
```

Note the double backslashes since to denote a literal backslash in text you need to use two in the string literal.

The `\S+@\S+` pattern simply matches one or more non-whitespace chars, `@`, and then again one or more non-whitespace chars.

The `\S+@\S+\.\S+` pattern does the same + it also then matches a `.` and again one or more non-whitespace chars.